# Why 199 / (1.0 / 0.1) is 19.9, but 199 * 0.1 is 19.900000000000002 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

When I use irb, I got this:

```
2.3.1 :001 > 199 / (1.0 / 0.1)
 => 19.9
2.3.1 :002 > 199 * 0.1
 => 19.900000000000002
```

I am just curious about this. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Floating point error, it's a problem with all computer programs. Try the same calculation in calc.exe in Windows.

Comment: @redcodefinal It's only a problem if you use floating points; many calculator programs don't exactly to avoid these precision problems; in most programming languages you can also use arbitrary-precision arithmetic when accuracy matters (e.g. when dealing with money). Floating point is typically used by default just because it's so much faster and because *usually* the accuracy is "good enough"...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Yeah that's what I'm saying. It has to do with the limit on the amount of decimal places. The reason we get a weird number is its the answer minus the floating point epsilon for that language.

Comment: @redcodefinal Well, my previous comment was somewhat pedantic −  I'm not sure why I even bothered posting it, I must of been drunk  − but there *are* ways around this accuracy problem at the penalty of performance (so not "all computer programs" have it) ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker It's not really even a performance issue, it';s a memory issue. There is only so much space we can divvy out to a float, and therefore only so much accuracy.